# Trying to retrieve Net Net Working Capital price for stocks

Tags: python, pandas

Code was working but now getting this warning message, I am confused because I'm not using frame.append anywhere, am I?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as yh

def nnwc(ticker):
    
    try:
        bs_ = yh.get_balance_sheet(ticker)
        stats = yh.get_stats(ticker)
        info = yh.get_quote_data(ticker)
    except:
        print(ticker + " is missing Docs")
        
    def inner():
            
        try:
            cash = bs_.loc["cash"][0]
            sti = bs_.loc["shortTermInvestments"][0]
            nr = bs_.loc["netReceivables"][0]
            inv = bs_.loc["inventory"][0]
            liab = bs_.loc["totalLiab"][0]
            share_price = info.get("regularMarketPrice")
            nnwc = (cash + sti) + nr + (.5 * inv) 
            nnwc2 = nnwc - liab
            shares = stats.set_index("Attribute")
            so = shares.loc["Shares Outstanding 5"][0]
            a = 0
            
            if so[-1] == "B":
                a += float(so[:-1]) * 1e9
            elif so[-1] == "M":
                a += float(so[:-1]) * 1e6
                
            nnwc_share_price = nnwc2 / a
            
            print(ticker + " -- regular market price" + " : " )
            print(share_price)
            print(ticker + " -- NNWC price : ")
            return nnwc_share_price
            
        except:
            print(ticker + " doesn't carry inventory")
          
    return inner()
```

Output:
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
table = table.append(elt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the yahoo fin library uses it so you get the warning.

As long as you keep your library version, not updating any, you can overlook the warning.